# Remove characters to right of first space in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, regular-expression

```
2492  some string continues here
```

I would like to convert this to

```
2492
```

in Bash. How would I go about that?

This feels close, but is not working:

```
var="2492  some string continues here  "
echo ${var%[[:space:]]*}
```

Comment: Will there never be leading whitespace?

Comment: If you are asking how to do it in bash you should probably not be using bash to do it. Use Perl or something.

Answer (score 15):

Because there are multiple spaces you want to use

```
${var%%[[:space:]]*}
# ...^^
```

to remove the *longest* trailing substring that starts with a space

With just a single `%` you're removing the shortest sequence of a space followed by zero or more characters, which is just the last space in the string.

```
$ echo ">$var<"; echo ">${var%[[:space:]]*}<"; echo ">${var%%[[:space:]]*}<"
>2492  some string continues here  <
>2492  some string continues here <
>2492<
```

---

If you're just looking for the *first word*, you can do this:

```
read -r word rest_of_string <<<"$var"
echo "I have: $word"
```

That will take care of leading whitespace, assuming you have not altered the IFS variable.

Comment: How about if there is a leading space in the string? ` 2492  some string continues here`

Comment: That will remove all the characters.

Comment: `[:space:]` character class includes space, tab, CR, NL, etc. So it's a catch-all for any whitespace.

Comment: `a=($var); echo "${a[0]}"` also works for accessing the first word in the case of leading whitespace.

Comment: You expose the value to filename expansion as well as word splitting unless you do `set -f` first

Answer (score 4):

There is the simple solution of using `%%` (`${var%% *}`)instead of `%` (`${var% *}`). That will remove everything (`*`) after an initial space.

```
$ var='2492  some string continues here'
$ echo "${var%% *}"
2492
```

But that will fail if the string in var has any leading spaces. It is possible to remove the leading spaces with:

```
$ var=$' \t 2492  some string continues here  '
$ var="${var#"${var%%[![:space:]]*}"}"
$ echo "$var"
2492  some string continues here  
$ echo "${var%%[[:space:]]*}"
2492
```

That works even if the white-spaces are spaces tabs NL or CR.

---

#### Regex

Maybe a more robust solution is to use a regex:

```
$ var=$' \t 2492  some string continues here  '
$ regex='^[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+)'
$ [[ $var =~ $regex ]] && var=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
$ echo "$var"
2492
```

Comment: I think that's the first time I've seen anyone refer to regular expressions as "more robust" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the simple tool `cut`,  who cuts strings based on a delimiter :

```
echo "$mystring" | cut -d' ' -f 1
```

Where :

- `-d' '` sets the delimiter to a space
- `-f 1` gives the first field (based on the delimiter)

Comment: I like this one. No regular expressions, no programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use native shell string manipulation:

```
TEST="test  1234 foo"
SPLIT_VAR=${TEST/ */ }
```

It will replace the first pattern matching " *" (one space then anything) and replace it with " " (one space). So you keep the first word and the first space.

You can see http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html for more usage of string manipulation.

And as a side note, it's also works less evolved shell (tested on busybox's ash implementation).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind an external call, use awk or sed:

```
$ string="first second third fourth"
$ echo "${string}" | awk '{print $1}' # will work even with tabs
first
$ echo "${string}" | sed -e "s/ .*$//" # will fail on leading whitespace
first
```

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells

Comment: Quoted my strings, thanks for catching that @Kusalananda

Answer (score 0):

To use only bash and builtin commands, you could use **Internal Field Seperator**(IFS) and  **arrays**

```bsh
set -f                # To prevent filename globbing when creating the array, as pointed out by Kusalananda in the comments
array=(2492 some string continues here)
set +f                # enable it again
IFS=" "
echo "${array[0]}"
unset IFS
```

Comment: Try that with a string that starts with e.g. `*`.

Comment: @Kusalananda tried it with `array=(*2492* *some * *string continues* here)`- **still works**

Comment: Now add a file in the current directory that contains `2492` in its name, for example `myfile-2492.txt`, and run again.

Comment: @Kusalananda oh wow, why does this happen ?

Comment: Filename globbing happens when you create the array of unquoted strings.

Comment: @Kusalananda **TIL**

Comment: @Kusalananda, I guess I'll have to start with `set -f` and end with `set +f` ?

Comment: That would be one solution to it, yes. You should also quote the `${array[0]}`.

Comment: Could you please explain the purpose of `IFS` here? `echo "${array[0]}"`, the only command between the assignment and deletion of `IFS`, doesn't include anything that would be subject to tokenization with the default setting but not with `IFS=" "` or the other way around.